# Do we have $ T_n=O(n^{-\frac{2}{3}})\le O_p(n^{-1/6})$ from the above results?

Tags: analysis

If we have a estimator $T_n=T_n(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ for $n$ iid random variables $X_1,\dots X_n$, and I want to prove that
$$
T_n=O_p(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})
$$
where $a_n\le n^{1/3}$.

It seems that we have
$$
T_n=O_p(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})\le O_p(n^{-1/6})
$$

Also, if I prove that for $n$ large enough
$$
E|T_n|^2=O(n^{-\frac{2}{3}}).
$$

Question: if $E|T_n|^2=O(n^{-\frac{2}{3}})$, can we show that $
T_n=O_p(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})
$ for $a_n\le n^{1/3}$?

---

Can we say
$$
T_n=O_p(n^{-\frac{2}{3}})\le O_p(n^{-1/6})?
$$

Also, since $T_n=O_p(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})$, then for every $\epsilon>0$
$$P(\sqrt{n}|T_n|/a_n\ge \epsilon)\le \epsilon $$
and by Markov inequality
$$
P(\sqrt{n}|T_n|/a_n\ge \epsilon)\le \frac{E|\sqrt{n}|T_n|/a_n|^2}{\epsilon^2}
$$

Comment: The question is then whether $O_p(n^a)$ goes to zero faster than $O_p(n^b)$ for $a<b<0$, right?

Comment: @Math-fun No. Question: if $E|T_n|^2=O(n^{-\frac{2}{3}})$, can we show that $
T_n=O_p(\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})
$ for $a_n\le n^{1/3}$?

Comment: I think the answer in negative: there is no reason for $T_n$ to be $O_p(n^{-a})$ for $a<1/6$ in general.